# AS3 I need to convert a string from input to an AS3 object 

Tags: actionscript-3, eval

How can I do this? Here's what I have:

```
function send(input):void{
   // input.text = "{key: 'value'}"
   var x:* = stringToObject(input.text)

   // then be able to do this
   var y:* = x.key;

   // then y must be equal to 'value'
   trace(y) // this is just a string
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to include the JSON library to be able to parse JSON strings into objects.

Reference the [as3corelib](http://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) library for more info.